# Advanced WPF TreeView with Multiselection, inplace editing, drag&drop, multi columns

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I know that they are a lot of WPF TreeView Controls out there, but I couldn't find a free one with the following features:

- Multiselection
- Multiple columns
- Full row selection
- Drag & Drop of items (change order, drag items onto nodes)
- Inplace editing (double-click on an item lets you edit the node directly within the tree)

Does anyone knows about such a control? Preferable for free, but I would also pay for a good solution.

[image]

I added a picture to make clearer what I mean:

full row selection = the full row is highlighted when an item is selected. In WPF's TreeView only the node is selected
Multi-Columns = the TreeView on the screenshot has 3 columns - Name, Last Modified and Size. The Columns are resizable (and optional sortable)

Comment: What do you mean by Multiple columns and Full row selection within a treeview? Can you provide more details on this

Comment: I just added a screenshot to my original question

Comment: You want the multiple selection in child items only or you want the tree items also to be selected?

Comment: Everything should be selectable. Items and Folder.

Comment: One Solution is to have a Datagrid as Child element where you want to display the actual information for photos...

Comment: the requirement here is too broad, no one can code a full control for you. So it appears to be off topic.

Comment: You can also use the concept of DataGrid within DataGrid where Datagrid goes as a row within the DataGrid but still it will not fulfill your complete requirement

Comment: As I'm just looking for the same thing, did you find a solution?